# Adding ComposeView to PopupWindow's contentView crashes

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, popupwindow, android-jetpack-compose, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to show a `PopupWindow` from a `Fragment`, and then add a `ComposableView` to the Popup `contentView`, and it crashes because the `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` is not found for `PopupDecorView$PopupDecorView`.

Things I've tried:

- Use the `PopupWindowCompat` to display the popup.
- Multiple lib versions for `Fragment` (1.3.4 and 1.4.0-alpha1).
- `Activity` version that I'm using is: 1.3.0-alpha08.
- Manually set the lifecycle owners for `contentView` and `ComposeView`.

Calls:

Add `ComposeView` to `contentView`:

```kotlin
 contentWindow.contentView.addView(
                AdaptiveCardistRender.adaptiveCardistResponseView(
                    contentWindow.contentView.context,
                    response
                )
            )
```

Show Popup:

```kotlin
PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(
                popupWindow,
                anchor,
                0,
                startVerticalOffset,
                Gravity.NO_GRAVITY
            )
```

Set lifecycle on the `PopupWindow`:

```kotlin
class ExtensionsPopupWindow(
    val contentView: ScrollView,
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
) : PopupWindow(contentView, width, height, true) {

    init {
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(contentView, lifecycleOwner)
        ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(contentView, savedStateRegistryOwner)
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{9dfea2f V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:242)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:153)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:200)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:235)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20665)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3493)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3500)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2057)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8501)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1005)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:826)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7727)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Are you using implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0' ?

Comment: Yup, I've forgotten to mention that as well

Comment: Can you add some code to have a reproducible example?

Comment: Have you got the answer for this? I'm having the same issue in my project. If you have the answer, please, share with me :)

Comment: No answer yet, ended up by using BottomSheet :(

Answer (score 2):

By default PopupWindow cannot work with compose.

There is some setup to do for compose to find :

- Content child
- ViewTreeLifecycleOwner,
- ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.

Here an example of how to show a popup from compose with a compose view inside the popup window.
(the most important part is the parentView)

```kotlin
val composeView = ComposeView(LocalContext.current).apply {
    setContent {
        // your composables
    }
}
val parentView = FrameLayout(LocalContext.current).apply {
    // Help compose to find View.contentChild
    id = android.R.id.content
    // Help compose to find ViewTreeLifecycleOwner
    ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, LocalLifecycleOwner.current)
    // Help compose to find ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
    ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(this, LocalSavedStateRegistryOwner.current)

    layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    addView(composeView)

}
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(
    parentView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
)

popupWindow.showAtLocation(LocalView.current, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    onDispose {
        popupWindow.dismiss()
    }
}
```

If you do it from a activity replace `LocalLifecycleOwner.current`, `LocalSavedStateRegistryOwner.current` and `LocalContext.current` by your activity.

Comment: I hope it works but i've again a crash with this error : 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to put **AbstractComposeView** in window popup as a workaround you can use compose **Popup** and still use the compose view as place holder inside view (it doesn't require height or width so it will not mess with your layout) then just show the popup with **IntOffset** where you want in the screen